# Checking for nan in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I'm looking for a way to check for NaN values in Cython code. At the moment, I'm using:

```
if value != value:
    # value is NaN
else:
    # value is not NaN
```

Is there a better way to do this? Is it possible to use a function like Numpy's `isnan`?

Comment: There's `math.isnan`. I'm not familiar with Cython; can you use such a builtin module?

Comment: (It seems you can, so I've made an answer of it.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Taken from http://groups.google.com/group/cython-users/msg/1315dd0606389416, you could do this:

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    bint isnan(double x)
```

Then you can just use `isnan(value)`.

In newer versions of Cython, it is even easier:

```
from libc.math cimport isnan
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make sure that your code also works on Windows you should better use

```
cdef extern from "numpy/npy_math.h":
    bint npy_isnan(double x)
```

because on Windows, as far as I know, isnan is called _isnan and is defined in float.h

See also here for example: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/186

If you don't want to introduce numpy you could also insert these precompiler directives into the .c file cython generates:

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(MS_WINDOWS)
#define USEMATH_DEFINES
#define isnan(x) _isnan(x)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both `x != x` and `isnan` from `math.h`, found the performance were almost the same, and both methods were about 20x faster than `np.isnan` from `numpy`.