# In-place shuffling of multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, cython

I am trying to implement a NaN-safe shuffling procedure in Cython that can shuffle along several axis of a multidimensional matrix of arbitrary dimension.

In the simple case of a 1D matrix, one can simply shuffle over all indices with non-NaN values using the Fisher–Yates algorithm:

```
def shuffle1D(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] x):
    cdef np.ndarray[long, ndim=1] idx = np.where(~np.isnan(x))[0]
    cdef unsigned int i,j,n,m

    randint = np.random.randint
    for i in xrange(len(idx)-1, 0, -1):
        j = randint(i+1)
        n,m = idx[i], idx[j]
        x[n], x[m] = x[m], x[n]
```

I would like to extend this algorithm to handle large multidimensional arrays without reshape (which triggers a copy for more complicated cases not considered here). To this end, I would need to get rid of the fixed input dimension, which seems neither possible with numpy arrays nor memoryviews in Cython. Is there a workaround?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So is the problem just having an arbitrary number of dimensions?

Comment: How many for-loops will you use when the dimension of the input is unknown?

Comment: @moarningsun it is possible to use the array strides in order to scan the memory along any axis for a general case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of @Veedrac this answer uses more of Cython capabilities.

- A pointer array stores the memory address of the values along `axis`
- Your algorithm is used with a modification [that checks for `nan` values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20031818/832621), preventing them of being sorted
- It won't create a copy for `C` ordered arrays. In case of `Fortran` ordered arrays the `ravel()` command will return a copy. This could be improved by creating another array of double pointers to carry the values of `x`, probably with some cache penalty...

This code is at least one order of magnitude faster than the other based on slices.

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint

cdef extern from "numpy/npy_math.h":
    bint npy_isnan(double x)

def shuffleND(x, int axis=-1):
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] v # view of x
    cdef np.ndarray[int, ndim=1] strides
    cdef int i, j
    cdef int num_axis, pos, stride
    cdef double tmp
    cdef double **v_axis

    if axis==-1:
        axis = x.ndim-1

    shape = list(x.shape)
    num_axis = shape.pop(axis)

    v_axis = <double **>malloc(num_axis*sizeof(double *))
    for i in range(num_axis):
        v_axis[i] = <double *>malloc(1*sizeof(double))

    try:
        tmp_strides = [s//x.itemsize for s in x.strides]
        stride = tmp_strides.pop(axis)
        strides = np.array(tmp_strides, dtype=np.int32)
        v = x.ravel()
        for indices in np.ndindex(*shape):
            pos = (strides*indices).sum()
            for i in range(num_axis):
                v_axis[i] = &v[pos + i*stride]
            for i in range(num_axis-1, 0, -1):
                j = randint(i+1)
                if npy_isnan(v_axis[i][0]) or npy_isnan(v_axis[j][0]):
                    continue
                tmp = v_axis[i][0]
                v_axis[i][0] = v_axis[j][0]
                v_axis[j][0] = tmp
    finally:
        free(v_axis)

    return x
```

Comment: It's worth putting the `free` in a `finally` block, but this looks neat. I don't understand the algorithm at all, so I'm trusting that's right.

Comment: Note that 1: `ravel` *can* copy, and 2: I think `(strides*indices).sum()` might not be sufficient for all cases. Consider `v[::2].strides`.

Comment: @Veedrac I tried `(strides*indices).sum()` with a couple of tricky inputs and it seems to work, and I added a remark that `ravel()` will copy if the array is Fortran aligned...

Comment: Will it work without copy for `numpy.array(10)[::2]`?

Comment: @Veedrac actually not, it seems the array must be `C` continuous in order to avoid getting a copy with `flatten()`...

Comment: Memory leak? Each `v_axis[i]` is initialized with a call to malloc(), but it appears that that memory is never used (`v_axis[i]` is later overwritten), and it is never freed.

Answer (score 2):

The following algorithm is based on slices, where no copy is made and it should work for any `np.ndarray`. The main steps are:

- `np.ndindex()` is used to run throught the different multidimensional indices, excluding the one belonging to the axis you want to shuffle
- the shuffle already developed by you for the 1-D case is applied.

Code:

```
def shuffleND(np.ndarray x, axis=-1):
    cdef np.ndarray[long long, ndim=1] idx
    cdef unsigned int i, j, n, m
    if axis==-1:
        axis = x.ndim-1
    all_shape = list(np.shape(x))
    shape = all_shape[:]
    shape.pop(axis)
    for slices in np.ndindex(*shape):
        slices = list(slices)
        axis_slice = slices[:]
        axis_slice.insert(axis, slice(None))
        idx = np.where(~np.isnan(x[tuple(axis_slice)]))[0]
        for i in range(idx.shape[0]-1, 0, -1):
            j = randint(i+1)
            n, m = idx[i], idx[j]
            slice1 = slices[:]
            slice1.insert(axis, n)
            slice2 = slices[:]
            slice2.insert(axis, m)
            slice1 = tuple(slice1)
            slice2 = tuple(slice2)
            x[slice1], x[slice2] = x[slice2], x[slice1]
    return x
```

Comment: It seems to me that this method has nullified any of the benefits of using Cython. Maybe it's good enough for user45893, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: @Veedrac thank you for the comment... I looked for another alternative using the array strides and came out with another answer... which I timed to be at least 10X faster than the solution based on slices...